# Calculate $\text{Tor}_n^R(k,k)$ for $R=k[x,y,z,w]/(xw-yz)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $k[x,y,z,w]$ be the polynomial ring in the indeterminates $x,y,z$ and $w$.     Let $R=k[x,y,z,w]/(xw-yz)$, then $k$ becomes an $R$-module via the homomorphism $R\rightarrow k[x,y,z,w]/(x,y,z,w)\cong k$.

I attempt to find $\rm{Tor}$$_n^R(k,k)$ for $n>0$. By definition, I should find a projective resolution of $k$. I guess there may be a free resolution of $k$ of the form

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad...R^4\rightarrow R\rightarrow k\rightarrow 0$,

where $R^4\rightarrow R$ is defined by $(\bar{a},\bar{b},\bar{c},\bar{d})\mapsto \overline{ax+by+cz+dw}$ for all $(\bar{a},\bar{b},\bar{c},\bar{d})\in R$. But I am stuck here and cannot find a good way to describe the kernel of $R^4\rightarrow R$.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: To find the kernel of this map, it is a good idea to have a $k$-basis of $R$. Do you have one?